# Binding a Model From Query String in Bracket Notation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Superfluous comment:  I cannot believe I couldn't find a clear answer for this anywhere yet!

Using ASP.NET MVC model binding requires use of dot notation (`variableName.propertyName`) when using a query string.  However, jQuery will use bracket notation when using a GET request, such as `variableName[propertyName]=value&`.  ASP.NET MVC cannot understand this notation.

If I issued a POST request ASP.NET is able to properly bind the model because it uses dot notation in the posted body.

Is there any way to force ASP.NET to bind to a model that is a complex object when bracketed notation is used within a query string?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution, but I solved this using some reflection magic by implementing a generic implementation of `IModelBinder`.  The stipulations on this implementation is that it assumes the elements from JavaScript in the query string are in camelCase and the class in C# is in PascalCase per standard styles.  Additionally, it only functions on public [set-able] properties.  Here's my implementation below:

```
public class BracketedQueryStringModelBinder<T> : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(p => p.CanWrite);
        Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            if (!IsNullable(p.PropertyType))
            {
                object val = TryGetValueType(p.PropertyType, bindingContext, p.Name);
                if (val != null)
                {
                    values.Add(p.Name, val);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                object val = GetRefernceType(p.PropertyType, bindingContext, p.Name);
                values.Add(p.Name, val);
            }
        }

        if (values.Any())
        {
            object boundModel = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            foreach (var p in properties.Where(i => values.ContainsKey(i.Name)))
            {
                p.SetValue(boundModel, values[p.Name]);
            }

            return boundModel;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static bool IsNullable(Type t)
    {
        if (t == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("t");

        if (!t.IsValueType)
            return true;

        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) != null;
    }

    private static object TryGetValueType(Type type, ModelBindingContext ctx, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        key = ConvertToPascalCase(key);

        ValueProviderResult result = ctx.ValueProvider.GetValue(string.Concat(ctx.ModelName, "[", key, "]"));
        if (result == null && ctx.FallbackToEmptyPrefix)
            result = ctx.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);

        if (result == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            object returnVal = result.ConvertTo(type);
            ctx.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, result);
            return returnVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ctx.ModelState.AddModelError(ctx.ModelName, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static object GetRefernceType(Type type, ModelBindingContext ctx, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        key = ConvertToPascalCase(key);

        ValueProviderResult result = ctx.ValueProvider.GetValue(string.Concat(ctx.ModelName, "[", key, "]"));
        if (result == null && ctx.FallbackToEmptyPrefix)
            result = ctx.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);

        if (result == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            object returnVal = result.ConvertTo(type);
            ctx.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, result);
            return returnVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ctx.ModelState.AddModelError(ctx.ModelName, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static string ConvertToPascalCase(string str)
    {
        char firstChar = str[0];
        if (char.IsUpper(firstChar))
            return char.ToLower(firstChar) + str.Substring(1);

        return str;
    }
}
```

Then in your controller you can use it like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult myAction([ModelBinder(typeof(BracketedQueryStringModelBinder<MyClass>))] MyClass mc = null)
{
    ...
}
```

The main downfall to this method is that if you do get a query string in dot notation this binding will fail since it doesn't revert back to the standard model binder.